# Unable to set JAVA_OPTS variable -Dweceem.config.location for Weceem Grails CMS

Tags: java, grails, classpath, tomcat6, java-opts

I am trying to have Weceem (Grails CMS) installed locally on my machine (Windows XP), but I am having a really hard time setting the JAVA_OPTS variable **-Dweceem.config.location**.

My environment is as follows:

1. Java 6 with **JAVA_HOME** environment variable added to the **Path**
2. Tomcat 6 Installed
3. Grails 1.3.7 installed and set under **GRAILS_HOME** variable and added to the **Path** environment variable.
4. MySQL Installed
5. MySQL JDBC jar added under Tomcat_home/lib folder.
6. A Database called **weceem** with **weceem** as username and password created and full permissions to create all kinds of database objects.

**PROBLEM**

In order to install WECEEM GRAILS CMS you have to have a weceem.properties files in Tomcat's classpath. I am having a hard time setting that up. I did as follows:

1. Created a **weceem.properties** under tomcat_home/lib with the settings as follows:

   ```
   dataSource.pooled=true
   dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   dataSource.username=weceem
   dataSource.password= weceem
   dataSource.dbCreate=update
   dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weceem
   ```
2. Opened up **tomcat6w.exe** and added the following JAVA_OPT under **Java Tab\Java Options textarea:**

   **-Dweceem.config.location=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\weceem.properties**
3. Place **weceem-1.1.2.war** under **tomcat_home\webapps**
4. Double click on **tomcat6.exe** under **tomcat_home\bin**
5. Everything seems to be deploying/initializing fine but I notice that at the beginning it says: Classpath resource[C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\weceem.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist.

Anybody has any ideas on how to fix this?

Any good step by step detailed solution on how to install Weceem?

Thanks,
Viriato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it to work on Linux. It also gave me a lot of headaches but this is what I did:

```
CREATE DATABASE weceem CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER 'weceem' IDENTIFIED BY 'weceem'; 
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'weceem'@'%';
```

Then put the **weceem.properties** file under **tomcat_home/conf**. Replace localhost with your servername or server IP Address.

```
   dataSource.pooled=true
   dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   dataSource.username=weceem
   dataSource.password= weceem
   dataSource.dbCreate=update
   dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weceem
```

Finally, edit **catalina.sh** with the following right after the Header comments

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -    
XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -
XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dweceem.config.location=file:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-
6.0.32/conf/weceem.properties"
```

If anybody knows how to do it on Windows please share because I do not have the equivalent catalina.sh (catalina.bat) in my tomcat_home/bin folder.

Comment: @ Viriato : +1 . Thanks for answering. I updated the windows part below.

Answer (score 1):

I used weceem on windows(with postgres). Steps tweaked from above

create `c:/apps/weceem/`
create a file `weceem.properties` in above folder.  Contents below

```
# Control whether or not connection pooling is enabled
dataSource.pooled=true

# Set the JDBC driver class name - class must be on classpath
dataSource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
# The user name for the SQL databasee
dataSource.username=weceem
# The password for the SQL database
dataSource.password=weceem
# The database update mode. Leave as "update"
dataSource.dbCreate=update
# The JDBC URL of your database
dataSource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/weceem

# OR you can specify a JNDI data source with just this line, and nothing else
# but you must have configured the JNDI database resource in your servlet container/
#dataSource.jndiName=java:comp/env/jdbc/WeceemDS

# The path to use for storing search index files - MUST be writable
searchable.index.path=c:/temp/weceem/search-indexes
```

Created a setenv.bat just one line

```
set  CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx1100m -XX:MaxPermSize=300m -Dweceem.config.location=file:///C:/apps/weceem/weceem.properties
```

The filename must be retained. It  must be in tomcat's bin directory. The catalina.bat sources values from the file.  Also note that  `weceem.config.location` is **URL**  , so must starts with `file:///`
)

I copied postgresqljdbc.jar to the applications lib area ( `tomcathome\webapps\weceem-1.1.2\WEB-INF\lib` )

Created user and database in postgres

```
postgres=# create user weceem password 'weceem';
postgres=# create database weceem owner weceem encoding 'UTF8';
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that I had a weird installation of tomcat 6 on my local environment. I did not have the catalina.bat and other files, so I was not sure where to add it, so I reinstalled tomcat and i was able to set it.